# RequestMapping ; java Spring

Tags: java, spring, web-services, request-mapping

I want make simple web service using java spring restful web service .
I Use request Mapping annotation in controller class but when i run project there is no mapping there .
Here is controller Class :

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import guru.webservice.domain.Customer;
import guru.webservice.services.CustomerService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(CustomerController.BASE_URL)
public class CustomerController {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "api/v1/customers";
    private final CustomerService customerService;

    public CustomerController(CustomerService customerService) {
        this.customerService = customerService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {
        return customerService.findAllCustomer();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Customer getCustomerById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return customerService.findCustomerById(id);
    }
}
```

[image: heare is out put]

Comment: Show the request and headers

Comment: What happens when you change the value of BASE_ULR to `/api/v1/customers`? Do you see the mapping in the logs when starting the app? Have you debugged the code to see if this controller is instanciated by Spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To let Spring scan and configure @Controller annotated classes, you need to configure component scanning on packages where controllers are stored.

i.e: `/src/main/java/guru/webservices/spring/config/AppConfig.java`

### AppConfig.java:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc //THIS
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "guru.services") //THIS
public class AppConfig {

}
```

Also:

```
@Autowired
private CustomerService customerService;
```

And then:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity getCustomerById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {

    Customer customer = customerDAO.get(id);
    if (customer == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity("No Customer found for ID " + id, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity(customer, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```